# jquery validation events on submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have tried to use jquery url validation on this url http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ajaxSubmit-intergration-demo.html, in this example first validation occur when I try to enter a username and password and the second validation occur when i submit. how does that validation occur only when I submit?

Hope help,

Thanks

Comment: the plugin has the ability to define which events trigger the validation, you should read the documentation

Comment: sorry a problem is i dont read all explanation from the documentation, a problem was solved, i just to add a option `onkeyup: false`. thx for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the page source, onsubmit validation occurs here:

```
var v = jQuery("#form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                target: "#result"
            });
        }
    });
```

The validation function knows how to validate each form field based on the DOM element attributes:

```
<p>
        <label for="user">Username</label>
        <input id="user" name="user" title="Please enter your username (at least 3 characters)" class="required" minlength="3" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="pass">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required" minlength"5" />
    </p>
```

The class="required" tells the validation plugin that the user must enter a value into that text field. The minlength attribute does exactly what you think it would, it sets the minimum length that a field entry may be. You can see from their page source a few typos in the password element. They meant to set the minimum length to 5 but forgot an equal sign.

Does this answer your question?

To validate a form: grab it with a jquery selector and use the validate function:

```
$("#myForm").validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is i just need to add a `onkeyup options: false`. so the validation does not happen when I try to enter some text to the input field.

```
        var v = jQuery("#form").validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                target: "#result"
            });
        }
    });
```